# How do I prove that $\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{x}{(1+x^7)^{1/3}}dx$ converges?

Tags: improper-integrals

How do I prove that $\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{x}{(1+x^7)^{1/3}}dx$ converges?

I wanted to do a comparison test with the integral $\int^{+\infty}_0\frac{x}{(1+x)^{1/3}}dx$, but it diverges. I can't seem to find a function which I would compare this to. If I could get a hint that would be great.

Comment: Hint: $1+x^7>x^7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x^{7})^{1/3}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(1+x^{7})^{1/3}}\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+x^{7})^{1/3}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(1+x^{7})^{1/3}}\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{x^{7/3}}\mathrm{d}x\\\\
& = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(1+x^{7})^{1/3}}\mathrm{d}x + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{4/3}}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! How do I show that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{(1+x^{7})^{1/3}}\mathrm{d}x$ converges? I know it's convergent but not sure how exactly

Comment: @use80085 the integrand is continuous over $[0,1]$, so the integral is an ordinary Riemann integral. No need to establish convergence.

Comment: oh okay in know there's a rule for this, forgot that